# Get the path of the particular clicked image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Demo is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/zkvaoata/3/)

When I click on any image, I want to get the path of that image. The problem here is that only the path of image 1 is being given every time.

Also, with that new src, i want to add that src in the image having id= cropimage

```
$(".img").click(function() {
    var newsrc = $(".img").attr("src");
    alert(newsrc);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`$(this)`** inside click event handler to get the element that is clicked. `$(this)` inside event handlers is the element on which the event has occurred.

If you use `$('.img')`, it'll select all the elements having class `img` and when use `attr` on it, it'll return the attribute value of the first matched selector.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zkvaoata/7/)

```js
$(".img").click(function() {
  var newsrc = $(this).attr("src");
  $('#cropimage').attr('src', newsrc);

  // Even Shorter Form
  // $('#cropimage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```css
#cropimage {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
<br/>
<img class="img" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/icons/hpcg/ribbon-black_68.png" />
<div id="img-container">
  <img src="" id="cropimage" />
</div>
```

Comment: yeah. that worked but I also want to add that src to the image in the div and then I want to show that Image in that div.

Comment: Thanks, I had put a question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716189/insert-the-image-sources-one-after-another-image . plz check this @Tushar

Answer (score 0):

Please check this  link [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkvaoata/10/) it will help you.

```
$( ".img" ).click(function() {
  var newsrc=$(this).attr("src");
    //alert(newsrc);
    $( "#cropimage" ).attr("src",newsrc);

});
```